# Tight VNC server doesn't have bars on windows

Tags: vnc

As seen below, all the windows I create have no top bar when I connect through vnc. If I use a monitor, they show up but I'd like to use the pi remotely. Is there a reason for their disappearance?

[image: Windows without top bar]

Edit:
Using the latest Raspbian image.

Comment: Which OS & version? On PiOS bullseye the problem could be the switch from openbox to mutter

Comment: I'm using the latest raspbian image so its bullseye

Comment: That worked, if you could submit an answer I'll close the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to switch from mutter to openbox.
[From here.](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323641)

`sudo vim /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/desktop.conf`

Change the second line from `mutter` to `openbox`